# Regex issue with comma's telling me there are 6 args, instead of intended 4

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I have a scenario outline table that looks like the following:

```
Scenario Outline: Verify Full ad details
    Given I am on the xxx classified home page
    And I have entered <headline> in the search field & clicked on search
    When I click on full details
    Then I should see <headline> <year> <mileage> <price> displaying correctly and successfully

    Examples:
    |headline               |year   |mileage    |price      |
    |alfa romeo 166         |2005   |73,000     |6,990      |
```

When I run my scenario it spits out that I have 6 args.
But what I thought, I should only have 4 args: headline, year, mileage and price.
I am thinking that it is taking the comma's and what is before and after it as two seperate args.

Is there any way that I can make cucumber think that there are only 4 args with the example below?

I have looked at messing around with regex but I dont seem to be getting anywhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you spitting that result out into a csv, then splitting on commas? That'd explain why you're getting 6 args - the `73,000` and `6,990` are being split into 4 separate numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is the last step that you are having issues with.

When I tried the last step, the default Cucumber step given was:

```
Then /^I should see alfa romeo (\d+) (\d+) (\d+),(\d+) (\d+),(\d+) displaying correctly and successfully$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

I am not sure how Cucumber determines the suggest step definition, but this is not one that will work for you. As you said, there are incorrectly 6 arguments. As well, the step will only match examples where the headline starts with 'alfa romeo'.

Changing the step definition to the following will solve your current scenario example:

```
Then /^I should see (.+) (\d+) ([\d|,]+) ([\d|,]+) displaying correctly and successfully$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4|
    puts arg1   #=> alfa romeo 166
    puts arg2   #=> 2005
    puts arg3   #=> 73,000
    puts arg4   #=> 6,990
end
```

Two changes:

1) The comma formatted numbers were changed to:

```
([\d|,]+)
```

which means that it will matching any number or comma character. If your numbers can also include decimals, you'll want something like:

```
([\d|,|.]+)
```

2) The heading was also changed so that it to get the entire headline rather than just the ending number.

Comment: Note that this solution is assuming you only use comma formatted numbers. If you are also testing French (ie numbers like '1 000,20') then one of the other solutions will be better.

Comment: Thanks Justin, your solution is working for me. I will post my step definitions by the weekend. Once again thanks

Answer (score 0):

As 73,000/6,990 is just an int, can you just enter it as 73000/6990 (without the commas)? I dont see this causing a problem, unless you require this format for some reason?

Comment: I need the comma format, as I want to verify the values as they are on the front end

Answer (score 0):

A good way of formatting numbers in this case is to use underscores instead of commas or periods. You avoid locale issues (1.000 vs 1,000) and keep some formatting.

```
|headline               |year   |mileage    |price      |
|alfa romeo 166         |2005   |73_000     |6_990      |
```